# How To render Silex Forms in Smarty Template?

Tags: php, symfony, smarty, silex

I just stuck at a point.

To render Forms in Smarty Template.
Well, smarty is well configured in my silex project.

here is the Code in my controller class.

```
$loginForm = $app['form.factory']
            ->createBuilder(new Form\UserLogin())
            ->getForm();

$app['smarty']->assign('loginForm', $loginForm->createView());


return $app['smarty']->render('login.tpl');
```

Here is the code in my tpl file

```
{block name="headline"}
<h1>User Login</h1>
{/block}


{block name="content"}
<div>
    {form_widget(loginForm)}
</div>
{/block}
```

And i am getting this exception.

```
SmartyCompilerException: 
Syntax Error in template "/home/Symfony/demo/App/View/login.tpl" on line 8
"{form_widget(loginForm)}" unknown function "form_widget"
```

Edit:

Ok i found the issue but not getting the solution.

Following is SmartyServiceProvider Class.

```
<?php

namespace App\ServiceProvider;

use Silex\Application;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;
use App\Classes\Smarty;
use NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Form\SmartyRendererInterface;
use \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\FormExtension;
use \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Form;

class SmartyServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{


    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app['smarty.auto-render'] = true;
        $app['smarty.extension'] = $app->protect(
            function (AbstractExtension $extension, Smarty $smarty = null) use ($app) {
                if ($smarty == null) {
                    $smarty = $app['smarty'];
                }
                /** @var $plugin \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\Plugin\AbstractPlugin */
                /** @var $filter \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\Filter\AbstractFilter */
                foreach ($extension->getPlugins() as $plugin) {
                    //print $plugin->getName() . " | " . $plugin->getType() . "<br>";
                    $smarty->registerPlugin($plugin->getType(), $plugin->getName(), $plugin->getCallback());
                }
                foreach ($extension->getFilters() as $filter) {
                    $smarty->registerFilter($filter->getType(), $filter->getCallback());
                }
            }
        );
        $app['smarty.extensions'] = $app->protect(
            function (array $extensions, Smarty $smarty = null) use ($app) {
                foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
                    $app['smarty.extension']($extension, $smarty);
                }
            }
        );
        $app['smarty'] = $app->share(
            function () use ($app) {

                $app['directory.smarty.plugins'] = $app['directory.root.app'] . '/Classes/Smarty/Plugins';

                $smarty = isset($app['smarty.instance']) ? $app['smarty.instance'] : new Smarty(
                    $app,
                    isset($app['smarty.primary.template.dir'])
                            ? $app['smarty.primary.template.dir']
                            : $app['directory.root.view'],
                    false
                );

                if (isset($app["smarty.options"]) && is_array($app["smarty.options"])) {
                    foreach ($app["smarty.options"] as $smartyOptionName => $smartyOptionValue) {
                        $smarty->$smartyOptionName = $smartyOptionValue;
                    }
                }

                $smarty->assign("app", $app);

                if (isset($app['smarty.configure'])) {
                    $app['smarty.configure']($smarty);
                }

                $extensions = [];
                //$extensions[] = new \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\FormExtension();
                $extensions[] = new \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\RoutingExtension($app['url_generator']);
                $extensions[] = new \App\Classes\Smarty\HookExtension();
                $app['smarty.extensions']($extensions, $smarty);

                return $smarty;
            }
        );
    }


    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
    }


}
```

Here in that class i have loaded extensions of SmartyBundle here.
Here I'll have to load FormExtensions.

```
$extensions = [];
$extensions[] = new \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\FormExtension('Don't know how to get SmartyRendererInterface instance here');
$extensions[] = new \NoiseLabs\Bundle\SmartyBundle\Extension\RoutingExtension($app['url_generator']);
$extensions[] = new \App\Classes\Smarty\HookExtension();
$app['smarty.extensions']($extensions, $smarty);
```

Comment: `form_widget` is a macro of the Twig-template engine, isn't it? So you'll probably need a smarty specific function for that purpose.

Comment: @LouisH. Please check i have put some edits in my question. have a look methods of the SmartyBundle for form rendering [link](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/Extension/FormExtension.php) its exactly the same as twig provides.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the Form Widget is:

```
{form_widget form=$loginForm}
```

From your example it's not clear the out from $loginForm->createView() and you're lacking the form tags ( ie  )that normally surround the Form widget. If the createView includes these you make be not need the form widget and just need to output the entire form HTML as:

```
{$loginForm}
```